# how to assign a value during\after if

Tags: python, python-2.7, if-statement, assign

Why can i not assign the value of ES? My values are .5, 13, and 2 although nothing comes from the 2 yet
This is the error

> in 
>       print ("Allowance ="), ES NameError: name 'ES' is not defined

```
import math

D = input("Nominal Size: ")
TPI = input("TPI: ")
TOL = input("Tolerance Class 1, 2, 3: ")
P = float(1.0/TPI)
H = float((math.sqrt(3)/2)*P)
D2 = float(D-2*.375*H)
D1 = float(D-2*.625*H)


if ((0.05*(pow(P,2)**(1/3))+(0.03*(P/D)))-0.002) < (0.25*P)-(0.4*pow(P,2)):
    ES = float((0.25*P)-(0.4*pow(P,2)))

print ""
print ("Pitch ="), P
print ("Fundamental Triangle Height ="), H
print ("Allowance ="), ES
print ("Basic Pitch Diameter ="), D2
print ("Basic Minor Diameter ="), D1
```

Answer (score 3):

`ES` is only set if the impenetrable condition:

```
((0.05*(pow(P,2)**(1/3))+(0.03*(P/D)))-0.002) < (0.25*P)-(0.4*pow(P,2))
```

is true. Obviously it is not.

If a suitable default value for `ES` exists you can set that beforehand, or in an `else` clause:

```
ES = 0    # whatever default is valid
if ((0.05*(pow(P,2)**(1/3))+(0.03*(P/D)))-0.002) < (0.25*P)-(0.4*pow(P,2)):
    ES = float((0.25*P)-(0.4*pow(P,2)))
```

or

```
if ((0.05*(pow(P,2)**(1/3))+(0.03*(P/D)))-0.002) < (0.25*P)-(0.4*pow(P,2)):
    ES = float((0.25*P)-(0.4*pow(P,2)))
else:
    ES = 0    # whatever default is valid
```

If there is no suitable default, then you could initialise/set `ES` to `None` and then explicitly check when printing:

```
print ("Allowance ="), ES if ES is not None else '?'
```

(or possibly `'None'` is actually a reasonable thing the print)

Comment: my problem is with '(pow(P,2)**(1/3))' i am using 13 for P but it is returning 1.0 it should be 0.180872

Comment: In Python 2 `/` is integer division, thus `1 / 3` is 0, not `0.3333...` Try changing it to `(pow(P,2)**(1/3.0))`, i.e. make `3` a float. Then the result of that expression will be `5.528774813678871`.

Comment: Similarly `P/D` may not be giving you what you expected.

Comment: P will always be not an integer. You are inversing an integer. Like 13

Answer (score 0):

Simply assign a default value on the same scope that you want to use it. This will print 0 if the condition does not evaluate to true.

```
ES = 0
if ((0.05*(pow(P,2)**(1/3))+(0.03*(P/D)))-0.002) < (0.25*P)-(0.4*pow(P,2)):
    ES = float((0.25*P)-(0.4*pow(P,2)))

print ES
```

Comment: I checked the values i'm running and the if will come up as true. I assigned it like you have it and it returns 0?

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the value of those variables?

Answer (score 0):

Alright I got that one figured out. Thanks guys. I was doing, raise to the power than raise that to a power and that was messing me up and i changed from 1/3 to .333333 and I added ES, changed to TD1, above the if statement. I added P1 that does one exponent then that makes it to the if as half the raise it then raise it again. For those of you who didn't catch, I'm new to python. And, this is to calculate thread diameter major minor and pitch major minor.

```
import math

D = input("Nominal Size: ")                  ##Nominal thread size
TPI = input("TPI: ")                         ##Thread per inch
TOL = input("Tolerance Class 1, 2, 3: ")     ##Class 1A 2A 3A 1B 2B 3B
P = float(1.0/TPI)                           ##Thread pitch
H = float((math.sqrt(3)/2)*P)                ##Height of fundamental triangle
D2 = float(D-2*.375*H)                       ##Thread basic pitch diameter
D1 = float(D-2*.625*H)                       ##Thread basic minor diameter
P1 = pow(P,2)                                ##Lots of exponent stuff
SDT = .54127*P                               ##Single depth of threads
DDT = SDT*2                                  ##Double depth of threads
MiMDI = D-DDT                                ##Minimum Minor Diameter Internal
MiPDI = (D-(0.32475953*P)*2)                 ##Minimum Pitch Diameter Internal
ES = 0                                       ##Allowance
Td = 0                                       ##Major diameter tolerance of external threads
Td2 = 0                                      ##Pitch diameter tolerance of external threads
TD1 = 0                                      ##Minor diameter tolerance of internal threads
TD2 = 0                                      ##Pitch diameter tolerance of internal threads

if ((0.05*pow(P1,.33333333333)+(0.03*(P/D)))-0.002) < (0.25*P)-(0.4*pow(P,2)):
    TD1 = float((0.25*P)-(0.4*pow(P,2)))

MaMDI = MiMDI+TD1                                ##Maximum Minor Diameter Internal

print ""
print ("Pitch ="), P
print ("Fundamental Triangle Height ="), H
print ("Allowance ="), ES
print ("Basic Pitch Diameter ="), D2
print ("Basic Minor Diameter ="), D1
print ""
print ("INTERNAL THREADS")
print ("MINIMUM Minor Diameter ="), MiMDI
print ("MAXIMUM Minor Diameter ="), MaMDI
print ("MINIMUM Pitch Diameter ="), MiPDI
##print ("MINIMUM Pitch Diameter ="), MaPDI
```